# Tic Tac Toe does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

He, guys!
Would somebody be so kind, to tell me what's wrong?
I want to program a Tic Tac Toe game. But I don't want to mark the game fields with "O" and "X". No, I want to mark them with different colours. So, the problem I have, is that, one player should have the color blue and the other player should have the color red. So every time a player clicked on the game fied the other player should have the other color.
Like this:

- Player 1.: click --> blue
- Player 2.: click --> red
- Player 1.: click --> blue
- ...

But this does not work!!!
I would be very thankful, if some of you would be able to answer my question.

Source Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tic Tac Toe |</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetTicTacToe.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="field_7" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
                <td><div id="field_8" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
                <td><div id="field_9" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="field_4" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
                <td><div id="field_5" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
                <td><div is="field_6" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="field_1" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
                <td><div id="field_2" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
                <td><div id="field_3" class="gameBoard"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var count = 1;

        $(document).click(function() {
            for(i = 0; i < 10;) {
                if(count % 2 == 1) {
                    $('.gameBoard').click(function() {
                        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
                    })
                    count++;
                    i++;
                } else {
                    $('.gameBoard').click(function() {
                        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                    })
                    count++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        })
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your check for even clicks is wrong. Replace it with `if(count % 2 == 0)` and have a look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for further questions.

Comment: Using `count % 2 == 1` is okay do to dividing by 2. It just means it'll run on the other case not the `count % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Yes but the user clearly wants different colours for different clicks. hence it will always execute the `else`. Right? :)

Answer (score 2):

You should take advantage of how event binding works. If you do, you don't have to iterate over all the potential cells -- you know by the `event.target` which cell was clicked on. For example:

```
var playCount = 0;

$(document).click(function(event) {
    var cell = $(event.target).closest('.gameBoard');
    if (!cell.hasClass("played")) {
        if (playCount % 2 == 1) {
            cell
                .css("background-color", "pink")
                .addClass("played");
            playCount++;
        } else {
            cell
                .css("background-color", "blue")
                .addClass("played");
            playCount++;
        }
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hgr0wke/

If can also bind more appropriately to the cells so that you only get a click event when a cell is clicked on. For example:

```
var playCount = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.gameBoard', function(event) {
    var cell = $(event.target).closest('.gameBoard');
    if (!cell.hasClass("played")) {
        if (playCount % 2 == 1) {
            cell
                .css("background-color", "pink")
                .addClass("played");
            playCount++;
        } else {
            cell
                .css("background-color", "blue")
                .addClass("played");
            playCount++;
        }
    }
})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hgr0wke/1/

Comment: You know, I am new in jQuery!

Comment: Would it be better to have two classes for each player that has played the square then put styling separate from code

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I think that would make sense.

Comment: @user4825080 If this helps you, you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark (it will turn green) on the left side of the answer!